# Can't download certain images from web using python

Tags: python, image, python-requests

To improve my Vietnamese I've been reading Vietnamese comics so I was thinking I could download them in bulk to read offline using a python script.

I've gotten pretty much everything figured out except I've found that certain images aren't downloaded properly. For example, this code does not properly download the image:

```
import requests

url = 'http://i.boxtruyen.net/data/images/15985/547026/006-fix.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.content)
```

I get a 3kb junk file. This code does not seem to work on any images from the Vietnamese comic websites.

However, if I replace the URL with a different one:

```
import requests

url = 'https://read.mangadad.com/Mangadad/fairy-tail/chapter-1/1.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.content)
```

Then it works great and everything is fine.

I'm pretty confused about why this code will work almost every image I've encoutered, except for the ones on these Vietnamese comic websites.

Anyone understand what's going on?

Comment: Did you try to open your urls with the browser? I'm getting cloudflare error from the first, and normal image from the second. (Are you sure you're getting junk? Try to look inside that jpg file you save -- is it really HTML?)

Comment: yeah, the urls both open perfectly in my browser. The first one just doesn't save using the code here.
both of the saved files should be jpg files, I don't think one would be HTML. I don't think I understand what you mean?
what's a cloudfare error? I'm assuming you and I are having the same problem though given that both images are .jpg files and both open perfectly and can be easily manually saved in a browser

Comment: I cannot open the first image in the browser. I see error page from cloudflare instead (google if you don't know what cloudflare is). Did you look inside your broken jpg file? Rename it to 'image.txt' and look inside -- is it rubbish or is it HTML? Can you open the first URL in anonymous browser window (so no cookies come into play)?